# How to sort a list by the structures inside?

Tags: javascript, list

I'm making a calendar app and I'm trying to put two lists together and sort them by start time. Each index of the list has a structure inside with a start and end variable. I'm trying to move these indexes in order, with respect to the starting time variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.sort()` method of `Array` like this:

```
myArray.sort((elemA, elemB) => elemA.start - elemB.start)
```

Here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort